# How to open external web pages in browser?

Tags: java, android

I need help in integrating code for opening external links. I have added some code to open links in a browser however, webview would just open the link and not direct it to a browser. My URL are correct. This is a webview application.

```
package io.eulj.dongdaegu;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

    public AdvancedWebView webView;
    private ProgressBar mPbar = null;

     public static String url = "https://studywire.eulj.io/app";
    String webURL, webTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

...
... Irrelevant Code omitted
...
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //mPbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);

        webView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.newWeb);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setListener(this, this);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
                AdvancedWebView newWebView = new AdvancedWebView(MainActivity.this);
                WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
                transport.setWebView(newWebView);
                resultMsg.sendToTarget();
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        /*webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                mPbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mPbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });*/

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://studywire.eulj.io")) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        webView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);
        webView.setCookiesEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/noInternet.html");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        //if (id == R.id.share_btn) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = webTitle + ":\n" + webURL;
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "StudyWire");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
        //} else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //    return true;
        //}

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        webView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        webView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        webView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!webView.onBackPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebViewClient webViewClient= new WebViewClient(){
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you override the WebViewClient twice, so the last time you are dismissing the implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` you previously wrote (`setWebViewClient()` replace the current handler). Put the implementation of `onReceivedError` along with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in the same WebViewClient instance and remove the second one. Your code should looks something like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://studywire.eulj.io")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
            }
        }
    });

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/noInternet.html");
    }
```